# Not able to ssh over a public wifi network - Operation timed out

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

For some reason, I'm trying to access a server via ssh over a public wifi network, but I'm getting the error:

```
connect to host ***.***.***.*** port 22: Operation timed out
```

Upon further investigation, I found out I could not ping *any* remote server as well:

```
admin ~ $ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.216.46): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I never encountered this problem from my home network, and since I'm trying this from a Library's Public Wifi network, I wonder if it's the public network that's causing hindrances. I am however able to access the internet flawlessly through my browsers. Sorry I'm really not well versed with network stuff, but I'd appreciate any insights to get through this problem.

Comment: they probably only allowed port 80 (web) and 443 (https) and disabled pings

Comment: This is hardly a programming question, I believe there are more suitable networking SE sites for this. But anyway, it's likely just a firewall "issue" and thus there's not really that much you can do about it. Maybe exploiting some stuff to get a tunnel back to your own network and continue from there but nothing straightforward anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because port 22 is closed on that network. You could test the service over other network and it should work well. Whatever, if you are sure that port 22 is open, maybe check that in the remote machine is running SSH server and listening for clients at the port in question.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right about port 22 being closed on that network - as I'm able to login to the remote server through another network, i.e, my home.

Comment: @abe_of_spades How to solve enable 22 port I also able to login remote through other netwrok, 

I have two internet connection one is working and other is not